# Domain models in front end

Tags: javascript, web, architecture, domain-driven-design

I have been reading about the Domain driven design lately but I rarely see it in the web applications(or I may have failed to google it), I think we now have enough complexity to deal with in web application too.

I need a way to keep my models and business logic clean and least coupled and framework/library agnostic. For example today I am using AngularJS and tomorrow I may switch the UI to ReactJS.

Having said that I am trying to learn this with a simple example. Suppose I am trying to create Quote application with the following features:

**Given a Quote**

1. Can be upvoted / downvoted.
2. Can be starred.
3. Can be created by User (Goes in the review Queue).
4. An user can share it via (Twitter, Facebook etc).

**Given an User**

When not logged:

5. Can see random quote.
6. Can upvote / downvote a quote.
7. Can search a Quote by Title or Author.

When logged in:

1. Can create a Quote.
2. Can star a quote.

I am interested in how the above requirements can be achieved in keeping UI and business logic clean and separate.

I am not an expert but at present I can come with these requirements which may well change in future.

Comment: React with Redux (and Elm in itself) implements a paradigm of the event sourcing with clear separation of presentation and "logic", with an immutable store end "left-fold" style state updates for it.

Comment: For line of business applications I tend to have all logic on the server and very dumb clients. The only reason I'd have business logic on the client is to improve performance and user experience, but at the end you cannot trust the state of the UI so all that logic has to be replicated on the server anyway. The most complex logic I have in clients is view logic. If I find that business logic is creeping into the client I make sure this data is available from the payload returned from the server. What kind of business logic do you have in the clients?

Comment: By the way, for data synchronization in single page applications I just listen to the event stream coming from the server and re-issue affected queries. Therefore, there is minimal logic to keep the state up to date. If you can afford the performance hit then it's a good approach.

Comment: @plalx I am relying on the server because I may use some third party API to get quotes so, I want my server to just send me dumb JSON data and let my client handle it.

Comment: @CodeYogi Well by doing the aggregation and quote analysis on the client you will lose an opportunity to learn more about your domain. For instance, if quote gathering and analysis was done on the server you could track who's usually providing best quotes and if there is a trend, etc. Anyway, whatever you decide I feel that having an anemic model on the client-side is usually better. Business logic is encapsulated in service objects. Controllers will then use these services to gather information, construct view-models  and communicate changes.

Comment: I never really faced a scenario where rich domain models were beneficial on the client, but it could be the breed of systems that I'm building. If I was for instance, designing an in-browser IDE then this could be very different as I'd probably want the documents to be modeled client-side. Nevertheless, nothing stops you from returning rich models from your client-side services.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement MVC patterns both in the front-end and in the back-end(server side). For clean separation of responsibility and also team resources/expertise(api developers, UI developers), you can have the business logic exposed via REST APIs and the UI development using various client-side technologies (e.g angular, cordova, react, etc).

UI developers should be able to develop in isolation without the API. They will have to create their own Models, Views and Controllers (MVC). Similarly, API developers should be able to develop the business domain and expose the necessary operations (e.g CRUD) required by the business or the ubiquitous language. The API layer will have its own Models, Views and Controller.

Comment: I agree and would add that there will be domain knowledge duplication (e.g. validating business rules both in the front and back-end) but this is kinda normal, and domain knowledge duplication is definitely better than coupling. To say that this is normal, when you read about "falty clients" it is generally about a client which has not performed validations on its end prior to invoking back-end functions. And you do that already: when you integrate a Payment Gateway, you read the docs and enforce mandatory fields in your end before posting. This is domain knowledge duplication right there.